# React Styled Components - transform scale with props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to style a navbar and I want a menu to transition open. I am trying to do this by passing a prop to the styled component and then setting the value of transform based on the prop, however I cannot see to figure out the syntax to use a prop in the styled prop. Here's the code:

```
<MenuContainer display={showMobileMenu ? '' : 'none'}>
  <UL>
    <LI><A showMobileMenu={showMobileMenu} href="#">Sign in with Github</A></LI>
    <LI><A showMobileMenu={showMobileMenu} href="#">New Snippet</A></LI>
  </UL>
</MenuContainer>
.
.
.
const MenuContainer = styled.nav`
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  top: 100%;
  background: ${colors.headerBackground};
  width: 100%;
  display: ${props => props.display};
  transform: ${props => props.display === 'none' ? scale(1,1) : scale(1,0)};
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
`;
```

React is complaining that 'scale is not defined  no-undef'.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `scale` is `undefined` in javascript expression.
you have to write your CSS as a string in `javascript expression`.
for example like this:

```
  transform: ${props => props.display === 'none' ? `scale(0.7)` : `scale(1,1)`};
```

I have provided a simple code in the code sandbox for you:
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dirac-tb08v
more resources:
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Answer (score 0):

Related to this question, using props within the scale like so.

```
transform: ${props => `scale(${props.width}, ${props.height})`};
```